# How to set a cookie in express after successful api request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

So across whole of my application I am using `/api` route to mask my real api url and I proxy it in express like this:

```
  // Proxy api calls
  app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
    let url = config.API_HOST + req.url // This gets my api url from config
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res) // This pipes it through
  })
```

However I now need to check if when users post to `/api/authenticate` and get a successful response I need to set a httpOnly cookie with their token from within express. How could this be achieved? I would also need access to data returned by that response to grab a token.

Comment: Are you looking for http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie ?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo I believe that is a part of it, but I would also need to only set this cookie if response from a post request to `/api/authenticate` is successful (so code 200), so I get data from that response, specifically token and use it as a value for my cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understrand you exactly (and I don't have reputation to comment), but I think you can use the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). Example:

```
var request = require('request')
//declare this inside your route if you want to send some parameters you can use formData it accepts get or post requests
request.post(config.API_HOST + req.url, formData : { field : 'something' }, function(err, response, body) {
    //here you have the response from the route with the token you generated
    //and then you can pipe this to the proxy or send the token via res
    res.send({ token : response.token }) //or use res.cookie('token', response.token)
}
```

With this you can create a request and have everything returned to you before sending the data to the first response, don't forget to handle the err argument!